# Binding and connecting an android service outside an activity

Tags: android

I would like to bind and connect a service but not within an android activity. Is there a class witch could be extended to have a context necessary for binding?

What i am trying to do is to provid a simple java library using an android service. My library does not use a UI. I only need to bind and connect my service inside a class witch necessary have application context necessary to the binding

Thanks

Comment: "I would like to bind and connect a service but not within an android activity" -- why? Without an adequate explanation of what you are trying to achieve, you will get incomplete answers at best.

Comment: What i am trying to do is to provid a simple java library using an android service. My library does not need a UI. I only need to bind and connect my service inside a class witch necessary have application context necessary to the binding.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the context from your application class. Derive your own class from Application, and give it a static getApplication method. You can use that for creating services.

Note that without an Activity, binding to a service may be a little hard - if, for example, you're in a BroadcastReceiver, it's not going to be alive long enough for you to receive the callback after the service has been bound.

Comment: If you know how to test your code, it shouldn't be a problem. Statics are everywhere.

Comment: `Statics everywhere` - is a bad practice, if some code refer to a static method - you would not be able inject this referenced `static` logic by any mock. Statics are good for utilitie methods

Comment: I get this when trying to used and extended class of Application : 

 12-23 17:33:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17954): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 17:33:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17954):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
12-23 17:33:41.031: E/AndroidRuntime(17954):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)

Comment: I got a NullPointerException when calling bindService. It is throws by android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName

Comment: You should declare your custom Application class in the manifest, telling Android to instantiate it, in the android:name attribute of your application tag.

Comment: I declare my custom Application in the manifest, but still get NullPointerException : Unable to instantiate application myPackage.MyCustomApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: In a Broadcast Receiver, provided that the service you want to bind to is already running, binding can be performed by using `peekService`, which is synchronous and allows you to immediately operate on the service.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an application without default activity. Then extend base Service class. And do not forget to describe it in the manifest file.

Service has its own context.